# Wrapping a non-generic Django view

Tags: django, view, code-reuse

I want to inject one additional variable into the context of a [view](http://github.com/jtauber/django-email-confirmation/blob/master/emailconfirmation/views.py) that belongs to a 3rd-party application without editing the code of that application. Is there a way to do this by wrapping the (non-generic) view? It doesn't accept an extra_context parameter, so the approach described in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505703/how-to-chain-views-in-django) won't work. I know I could create a context processor, but that seems like a lot of overhead, having this variable available on every page when I just want it in one view. Or is there a way to narrow the scope of a context processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a context processor is the way to go, but with a splash of logic in there that checks the request path (for instance) and only bothers digging out and setting the variable for the occasions when it's needed

Comment: Ah, duh, I always forget you can do that. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Excellent avatar image, btw ;o)