# How does refreshing of jwt token work in django REST angular

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using this

http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#refresh-token

I am confused how to make it work. I have done all settings as said. Now how to make it work.

Currently i have code to get first token when user submits login and i save that token in cookie store. Then my request use that token for all requests. I have seen that token sometimes expries and i don't want that. so thats why i am using this

```
$http
    .post('/api-token-auth/', logData)
    .then(function (response) {
        // assumes if ok, response is an object with some data, if not, a string with error
        // customize according to your api
        if (!response.data.token) {
            _vm.authMsg = 'Incorrect credentials.';
            deferred.reject('Incorrect credentials.');
        } else {
            $cookieStore.put('djangotoken', response.data.token);
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'JWT ' + response.data.token;
            $http.get('/api/account/restricted/').then(function (response) {
                authService.loginConfirmed();
                $cookieStore.put('currentUser', response.data);
                $rootScope.$broadcast('user:login');
            });
        }
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }, function (x) {
            _vm.authMsg = 'Server Request Error';
            deferred.reject('Server Request Error');
        });
```

This is how i am using that token in every request

```
   $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + $cookieStore.get('djangotoken');
```

Now what do need to do to make refresh token work. I mean does user has to manually refresh the token or system will automatically do it. and at what point do i need to visit this url

```
url(r'^api-token-refresh/', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.refresh_jwt_token'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation so that you referenced was quite explicit.  Pass in an existing token to the refresh endpoint as follows [snipped description]:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"token":"<EXISTING_TOKEN>"}' http://localhost:8000/api-token-refresh/
```

You have to invoke the refresh URL to make it work.  That means either your client needs to monitor when it needs to refresh the token and so invoke the URL, or you could put some logic in the server to invoke this URL for a subset of requests where you expect the user to take a long time to traverse them all (e.g. filling in a long multi-page form).

If you decide to go for the latter you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505703/how-to-chain-views-in-django) useful.

Comment: Thanks. That is what i am not clear about. When do you think  we need to refresh it. i want to know  how/when people usually refresh the token.

Comment: @user3214546 That should be before you hit the time in the "exp" field.  Assuming you use the default settings, that would be 300s.

Comment: @user3214546 That comes down to the design of your program.  At some point you will issue a request to get the token.  On receiving the response, your client could just set a timer to pop just before the expiration time and use the callback to issue the refresh.

Comment: Thanks. That is what i was asking in my question . Any sample of how to do that. I mean the code of logging in person i have given in question. How can i update that code to refresh token as well

Comment: @user3214546: I've not used it myself (as I tend to deal with the server side), but a quick search shows that angular-jwt will just handle it for you if you set it up correctly.  For example: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/blob/master/docs/refresh-token.md

Comment: Thanks dude, that will do